# In which places is the Windows %PATH% defined?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

I ran a third-party install script which added its folders to the `%PATH%` variable in the Windows shell.

I want to get rid of it, but I can't find the place where they are defined. My current `%PATH%` variable seems to be a concatenation of:

- PATH for current user
- PATH for the entire system
- something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** This applies to Windows 7 (and I think to Vista as well):

- Start > Right-click on Computer > Properties.
- Advanced System Settings link (on left).
- Environment Variables button.
- You will find a *Path* variable under the *System variables* section.

  - Select it and click *Edit* button to edit it.
  - You may also find a *Path* variable under the *User variables* section. You can edit it also.
- When done, click OK three times.

**Tip:** The *Edit variable* window is not very user-friendly. Copy the contents to Notepad for easier editing, and then copy the edited version back.

[image: screenshot]

**2.** Some systems may contain a PATH variable in the *Volatile Environment*. This variable is normally created on a computer connected to domains and usually cleared off at log out. However, you may want to check whether a PATH variable persists in the *Volatile Environment*:

- Start > *type in* `regedit`.
- Run the `regedit.exe` program that is found in the search.
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volative Environment` in Registry Editor's left pane.
- If there is any entry with the name `PATH` on the right pane, ensure that the stored paths are not necessary^, then right-click the entry and click Delete.
- Click Yes to the message.
- Restart your computer for changes to take effect.

^ If any of the stored paths is necessary:

- Copy it to a `Path` entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`.

  - You will have to copy the text manually. There is no drag-and-drop copying in Registry Editor.
  - Double-click on the original entry to open the *Edit String* dialog, and then copy the necessary text.
- If there is no `Path` entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`:

  - Right-click an empty space in right page and choosing *New > String Value*.
  - Type the name `Path`.
  - Press Enter twice to save the name and open the *Edit String* dialog.
  - Paste in the copied text.
  - Click OK.

[*Source on Volatile Environment*](http://techsupt.winbatch.com/TS/T000001057F4.html) (See **Using Volatile Environment PATH** towards the end.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the components I want to get rid of seems to be defined elsewhere (http://i.imgur.com/bNstI.png). And now that my question has been closed I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. What do you get when you double-click on the Path variable(s) in the _Environment Variables_ window? Also, try using `setx` command to **reset** the Path variable to something other than its current value (you won't see the change in the same command window, so open a new one _after_ issuing `setx` command).

Comment: Both variables have empty contents when I click them in the GUI. Also, I tried the `setx` method like that : `setx path TEST` (Took ~10 seconds) <open new command window> `echo %path%` gives `;TEST;;u:\tools\bin;r:\tools;`. No luck.

Comment: You need to do this: `setx path TEST /M` (Do it in an Administrator command window.) The /M will change the Path in the _System variables_ section (bottom part in the dialog). Without the /M, the Path variable is changed (or added) in the _User variables_ section (top part in the dialog). Also if this doesn't work, try editing the variables in the _Environment variables_ dialog itself. (PS: The path shown in command window when you do `echo %path%` is a concatenation of **both** system and user Path variables.)

Comment: It did that, with no luck. (It was already empty). After a lot of googling, it turned out that the third component was the "Volatile Environment"'s PATH, which can't be modified using `setx`. I used `setenv.exe` which knows how to do that.

Comment: Also I don't have the rep to do that, but I think the linked answer (in the duplicate link) deserves to be updated.

Comment: @kbok wow I had no clue about *Volatile Environment*. But I found out it's stored in `HKCU\Volatile Environment`. I'll add it to my answer here, but I can't update the duplicate question's answer coz, well it's so damn long I can't even begin to tell where I must include this info! (You could help me with that. And you can suggest edits even if you can't edit. Your suggested edit will be placed in a queue and they get approved very fast.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Setx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command at the command prompt to edit environment variables persistently, as it affects the values stored
in the registry. `Setx` by default works on the user variables, and SetX with the `-m` option edits machine-wide environment
variables (and consequently must be run from a command prompt with administrative privileges). The **PATH** environment variable is
indeed a composite of current user and machine variables as stored in the registry.

Comment: Thanks, I learnt a new command `setx`. But to anyone using this command, be careful to not lose the current value of PATH variable by incorrect usage. `setx` does not provide a way to *edit* the value of an existing environment variable; it can only replace the value. It's better to use the GUI method to edit, especially if you're a novice user.

Comment: @ADTC: I do not understand your comment. Editing existing env. variables is exactly the purpose of setx, and is far easier to do at the command-line than using the tiny GUI window. Both methods can equally easily overwrite existing values. The same can be said for any third-party application.

Comment: No, what I mean is, in the GUI you have access to the existing value where you can place the keyboard caret anywhere in the existing text and *edit* that text. In `setx`, all you can do is *replace* the existing value with a new value. If you want to edit, you'll have to use `set` to get the existing value, then copy it to some other place like Notepad or the command line itself, edit it, then use `setx` to *replace* the existing value with the edited one. There is no *direct edit* (textbox-like) in `setx`. (If there is, please show me how it's done.)

Comment: PS: I do know it's easy to add a *new* path to the `PATH` variable using `setx` like this: `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\New\Path\Here"` but it's not easy to edit or remove existing paths in the `PATH` variable.